# What is the proper way to validate an object with SqlAlchemy when the validation involves several fields?

Tags: python, validation, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Class with a quite complex set of business rules. Imagine something like "If field A has value 4 and field B has value True, than field C must be an array with at least 2 elements" and so on.

I'm trying to prevent the users to add instances of this class that don't respect these rules. So the validation should happen both on creation and on update.

I saw that SqlAlchemy offers the validate method but it looks a little bit too complicated to setup when the validation includes multiple fields.

The alternative appears to be the `before_insert` and `before_update` events. Is this the proper solution in this case or I have another alternatives that I've not considered?

Comment: DB constraints / triggers.

Answer (score 1):

This does sound like a rather specific case. Even if it is possible within scope of DB constraints and/or SQLAlchemy you are only looking for these checks to be run on creation and update so why not introduce some kind of context processor.

Within init you can have:

```
def __init__(self, ..):
    # runs the checks and returns actions
```

Instead of using db.session.add(class_instance) create your own pseudo context processor:

```
def update_with_checks(class_instance):
    # runs the checks and returns either no action if fails or:
    db.session.add(class_instance)
```

Of course this lends itself to the problem that your database might have compromised integrity if data is created outside of the scope of your code. The only way to maintain a DB with integrity is to ensure the constraints are written into the database itself.